# Modify reset password link without modify vendor file in laravel

Tags: laravel, email, hyperlink, vendor, reset-password

I want to modify reset password link. I dont want to modify vendor file.

For example: 
I receive link from email: http://localhost:8000/password/reset?51e5bd40dab074e8975100a2e84c08f457ec54c4cf6e0349fbe07ff67978793f

Needs to be change:
http://localhost:8000/password/reset?token=51e5bd40dab074e8975100a2e84c08f457ec54c4cf6e0349fbe07ff67978793f&email=abc@xyz.com

How it is possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passwords#resetting-views. You can probably change the url in the view.

Comment: I want to modify in email link. I am working on API part only. so there are no template for reset

Comment: Then maybe checkout this link: http://novate.co.uk/changing-the-laravel-5-3-password-reset-email-text/